# Solving for a variable in a complex algebra equation with logs and powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

I have a follow-up question to my last one. I need to solve for `b` for the following:

$$d=\frac{s(\ln(o))^b}{s(\ln(g))^b}$$

Once again, this is beyond the level of several online algebra calculators.

Comment: Why do you need an online calculator? The RHS is just the ratio raised to the power of $b$.

Comment: Well, true. It's still a complex process to determine `b = ...`

Comment: Nothing complex about it.

Comment: For someone well versed in this math, of course it's simple. But, this isn't my line. Please feel free to answer the question.

Comment: If your equation was $d = a^b$ can you solve for b?

Comment: Yes, $$b=\frac{\ln(d)}{\ln(a)}$$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$d=\frac{s(\ln(o))^b}{s(\ln(g))^b}$$
 $$d= \left (\frac{\ln(o)}{\ln(g)} \right )^b $$
Taking logs of both sides ...
$$ ln(d)=b \ln  \left (\frac{\ln(o)}{\ln(g)} \right )  $$

$$ b  = \frac{ \ln(d)} {  \ln(\ln(o))-\ln(\ln(g))}  $$

Answer (score 1):

I interpreted $s(...)$ as being a function of one argument, as opposed to @WW1's answer where he interpreted it as a number multiplying both the numerator and the denominator of the fraction that could therefore be canceled. If my interpretation is correct, then

$$ d = \left(\frac{s(\ln(o))}{s(\ln(g))}\right)^b$$

Taking logs, we then get

$$ b = \frac{\ln(d)}{\ln(s(\ln(o)) - \ln(s(\ln(g))} $$

which cannot be simplified further.

Comment: Thanks, NickD. @WW1's answer is correct.